# Error message not being displayed; incorrect conversion

Tags: c#

```
Console.Write("Enter a limit to the prime numbers you want displayed: ");
userInput = Console.ReadLine();

int newUserInput = Convert.ToInt32(userInput);

if (!int.TryParse(userInput, out newUserInput))
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nThe value entered must be a whole number. Please try again: ");
}
```

Can someone explain to me why my error message isn't showing up, and why the `int newUserInput` line is getting the error that it's not formatted correctly?

Comment: Probably not without knowing the input.

Comment: Convert.ToInt32 will throw an exception, your if-statement afterward is too late, the crash has already occurred. Try placing the conversion after the if-statement.

Comment: Then, as Lasse said, your TryParse is too late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Console.Write("Enter a limit to the prime numbers you want displayed: ");
userInput = Console.ReadLine();

int newUserInput;

if (!int.TryParse(userInput, out newUserInput))
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nThe value entered must be a whole number. Please try again: ");
}
```

Just do your work here `int.TryParse(userInput, out newUserInput)`, not converting it before `TryParse`

Comment: That's great, thanks! One more thing: do I need to convert the string if I want to use the `userInput` in further *if* statements, or can I just use `newUserInput`? (If that makes any sense...)

Comment: @ElonMuskrat you should use `newUserInput`, it already contains parsed value if `TryParse` was successful.

Answer (score 0):

> It totally depends on what are you sending in with `Console.ReadLine()`

Also, see following:

`Convert.ToInt32` will throw `FormatException` if input is not correct for `Int32`. Refer [Convert.Int32(MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx)

Also it looks like you are overwriting the `Convert.Int32` again with `TryParse`. You actually dont need `Convert.Int32`

```
    Console.Write("Enter a limit to the prime numbers you want displayed: ");
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();

    int newUserInput;  //dont assign anything

    if (!int.TryParse(userInput, out newUserInput))
    {

        Console.WriteLine("\nThe value entered must be a whole number. Please try again: ");


    }
```